# How can I dynamically center a div in the screen with JQuery and Translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following problem: I want the tariffCard > div to be centered on the screen when clicked. I need the centering to be animated. Thereby, I decided to don't do it by changing the left/top position with JQuery, since it would make the animation rough.

Thus I choose to follow the following strategy:

- Calculate in how many pixels I would have to move the element in the X and Y axes in order to center it;

```
    var leftPos = $(this).offset().left;
    var topPos = $(this).offset().top;
    var cardWidth = $(this).width();
    var cardHeight = $(this).height();
    var docWidth = $(document).width();  
    var docHeight = $(document).height();  
    var main = $(this);

    var moveRight = (docWidth - cardWidth)/2 - leftPos;
    var moveTop = (docHeight - cardHeight)/2 - topPos;
```

- Use JQuery to change the css transform

```
    $('.selected').css({"transform": "translateX(-" + moveRight + ") translateY(-" + moveTop + ") !important"});
```

The following issues are catching me:

- For some reason, this pixel calculation seems to do not be correct. The card turns out to be offsetted to the right after de transform.
- I couldn't find a way of making this second piece of code working (the one that changes the css transform). Thus I had to test the aforementioned pixel calculation manually.

This is the entire code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tariffCards > div').click(function(){
    var leftPos = $(this).offset().left;
    var topPos = $(this).offset().top;
    var cardWidth = $(this).width();
    var cardHeight = $(this).height();
    var docWidth = $(document).width();  
    var docHeight = $(document).height();  
    var main = $(this);
   
    var moveRight = (docWidth - cardWidth)/2 - leftPos;
    var moveTop = (docHeight - cardHeight)/2 - topPos;
    // console.log(cardWidth)
    // console.log(cardHeight)
    // console.log(leftPos)
    // console.log(moveRight)


    // Cria o Overlay
    $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

    $("#overlay")
      .height(docHeight)
      .css({
         'backdrop-filter': 'blur(3px)',
         'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
         'left': 0,
         'position': 'absolute',
         'top': 0,
         'width': '100%',
         'z-index': 1
      }).fadeIn('3000', function(){
          $('#overlay').show();
      });
    // transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateX(-90%) !important;
    // console.log("")
    // Some com o scroll
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
    // Some com os outros Cards
    $(main).siblings().css("opacity", 0);
    
    // Gira e centraliza o Card @Rever centralização
    setTimeout(function() {
      main.toggleClass('not-selected');
      main.find('h3').css("opacity", 0);
      main.find('span').css("opacity", 0);
      main.toggleClass('selected');
      // Ainda tenho que pensar como centralizar isso de um modo responsivo
      $('.selected').css({"transform": "rotateY(-180deg) translateX(-100%) !important"});
             
      $('.form-report').click(function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
      });
      
      $('#name-input').focus();
    }, 200);  

    setTimeout(function(){
     // Organiza o form dentro do Card
      $('.selected .form-report').css({
          "display":"inherit",
          "opacity": 1,
          "transform":"scaleX(-1)"
      });
    }, 600);
  });
});
 
 // Ao clicar no Overlay
 jQuery('body').on('click', '#overlay', function(){

    var main = $('.selected');

    $('.form-report').fadeOut('300', function(){
      $(this).hide();
    });

    $('#overlay').fadeOut('300',function(){
    $('#overlay').hide();
    });

    main.toggleClass('selected');
    // $('.tariffCards > div')
    // .css({"transform":'rotateX(45deg) rotateY(-15deg) rotate(45deg)', "height":"180px"
    // });

    setTimeout(function() {
      main.toggleClass('not-selected');
      $('.tariffCards > div').siblings().css("opacity", 1);
      $('.tariffCards > div h3').css("opacity", 1);
      $('.tariffCards > div span').css("opacity", 1);
    }, 900);    

    // Reaparece com o scroll
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll')
    
    
 });
```

```css
.tariffCards {
  left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tariffCards > div {
  border-radius: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 180px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(-15deg) rotate(45deg);
  transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
  width: 330px;
}

.tariffCards > div h3 {
  bottom: 30%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  left: 20%;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.tariffCards > div span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 35%;
  opacity: .8;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 100%;
}
.tariffCards > .lren {
  background-color: #8063e1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #bd7be8, #8063e1);
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px rgba(34,50,84,0.5), 1px 1px 0px 1px #8063e1;
}
.tariffCards > div.movi {
  background-color: #3f58e3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #7f94fc, #3f58e3);
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px rgba(34,50,84,0.5), 1px 1px 0px 1px #3f58e3;
}
.tariffCards > div.flry {
  background-color: #2c6fd1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #21bbfe, #2c6fd1);
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px rgba(34,50,84,0.5), 1px 1px 0px 1px #2c6fd1;
}
.tariffCards > div.pard {
  background-color: #352f64;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #415197, #352f64);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 60px rgba(34,50,84,0.9), 1px 1px 0px 1px #352f64;
}

.not-selected{
  transition: all .4s ease !important;
  /*z-index: -1 !important;*/
}

.not-selected:hover {
  transform: rotateX(30deg) rotateY(-15deg) rotate(30deg) translate(-25px, 50px) !important;
}

.selected {
  height: 55vh !important;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateX(-280px) !important;
  z-index: 3 !important;
}

/*Formulário de inscrição*/
.form-report{
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 2s;
    width: 80%;
}

.form-report form{
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.form-report form input{
    color: black;
    width:100%;
}

.container-btn a{
    background-image: linear-gradient(56deg, #08AEEA 0%, #2AF598 100%);
    border:none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow:0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 4% 0;
    transition: all .2s;
    width: 70%;
}

.container-btn a:hover{
    transform: translateY(3px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HomePage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="tariffCards">
        <div class="lren not-selected">
            <h3>Lojas Renner<br><br>$LREN3</h3>
            <span>Atualizado em 2T19</span>
            <!--Form aberto ao clicar no relatório-->
            <div class='form-report'>
                <h2>Receba agora.</h2>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id='name-input' placeholder="Nome">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Seu Email">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Celular (SMS de Confirmação)">
                </form>
                
                <br/>

                <div class='container-btn'>
                    <a href="#"><img src='http://edufinance.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/noun_down-arrow.png' width='12%'>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="movi not-selected" id='movi3'>
            <h3>Movida<br><br>$MOVI3</h3>
            <span>Atualizado em 2T19</span>
            <!--Form aberto ao clicar no relatório-->
            <div class='form-report'>
                <h2>Receba agora.</h2>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id='name-input' placeholder="Nome">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Seu Email">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Celular (SMS de Confirmação)">
                </form>
                
                <br/>

                <div class='container-btn'>
                    <a href="#"><img src='http://edufinance.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/noun_down-arrow.png' width='12%'>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flry not-selected" id='flry3'>
            <h3>Fleury S.A.<br><br>$FLRY3</h3>
            <span>Atualizado em 2T19</span>
            <!--Form aberto ao clicar no relatório-->
            <div class='form-report'>
                <h2>Receba agora.</h2>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id='name-input' placeholder="Nome">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Seu Email">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Celular (SMS de Confirmação)">
                </form>
                
                <br/>

                <div class='container-btn'>
                    <a href="#"><img src='http://edufinance.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/noun_down-arrow.png' width='12%'>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pard not-selected" id='pard3'>
            <h3>Hermes Pardini<br><br>$PARD3</h3>
            <span>Atualizado em 2T19</span>
            <!--Form aberto ao clicar no relatório-->
            <div class='form-report'>
                <h2>Receba agora.</h2>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id='name-input' placeholder="Nome">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Seu Email">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Celular (SMS de Confirmação)">
                </form>
                
                <br/>

                <div class='container-btn'>
                    <a href="#"><img src='http://edufinance.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/noun_down-arrow.png' width='12%'>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='home.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a reason to not use css animations?

Comment: `leftPos` and `topPos` refer to the coordinates of the card's top left corner. Maybe taking into account the card's width/height should do it?

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser I feel like I'm being silly, but the reason why I decided to not use css animations is because I don't know how I would pass the calculated moveTop and moveRight position to the css.

Comment: @AnisR. In fact, I'm taking the card width and height into account with cardHeight and cardWidth variables

Answer (score 1):

if you have no issues with CSS, please use CSS to justify-content in the centre. 
**Why not JavaScript/Jquery**: out custom `javascript`/`jquery` logic can lead to `performance issues`, because when we align some element in `HTML` `DOM`, then element removed and render at specified places.

So, I don't think this is not a good idea to justify a div after rendering in a page.

**Why CSS**: when the object is about to render at that time `browser` will decide where to place Element in Page, so using `CSS` we save the multiple time of rendering of an element in the page.

so this may help

```
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I came out wrong. The element is positioned correctly when the page is rendered. The issue is that I want the element to move to the centre of the page when I click on it.

For example, after clicking at the first card, It was supposed to move to the center of the page, after rotating -180deg.

Comment: okay, you want some animation! and move the element in the centre

Answer (score 0):

You can do the animation part with CSS, and use a JavaScript click event that adds a class to the element:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("centerme");

el.addEventListener("click", moveToCenter);

function moveToCenter()
{
    if(!el.classList.contains("centered")){
        el.classList += "centered";
    }
}
```

```css
#centerme{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: dodgerblue;
     margin-left: 0%;
     transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

#centerme.centered{
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="centerme"></div>
```

Comment: I tried it with my code, but for some reason the problem remains: the card turns out to be offsetted to the right after the "margin-left: 50%".

Comment: Probably has to do with the position of the parent element

Comment: Even the divs being positioned as fixed, the issue keeps happening

Comment: The parent container needs to be 100% of the width you want to use. Otherwise, check the margin-left and transform properties to make sure they're not being partially overridden.

Answer (score 0):

okay try this, made some changes in your code, and i was able to achive it

**basic changes**

added one more class

```
body
{
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  -webkit-justify-content: center; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

and

```
.selected {
  height: 55vh !important;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateX(0px) !important;
  z-index: 3 !important;
}
```

`translateX(0px)`

and remove some positions and left margins

here is running code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .tariffCards {
  left: 25%;
  top: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tariffCards > div {
  border-radius: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 180px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(-15deg) rotate(45deg);
  transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
  width: 330px;
}

.tariffCards > div h3 {
  bottom: 30%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  left: 20%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.tariffCards > div span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 35%;
  opacity: .8;
  top: -6%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 100%;
}
.tariffCards > .lren {
  background-color: #8063e1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #bd7be8, #8063e1);
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px rgba(34,50,84,0.5), 1px 1px 0px 1px #8063e1;
}
.tariffCards > div.movi {
  background-color: #3f58e3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #7f94fc, #3f58e3);
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px rgba(34,50,84,0.5), 1px 1px 0px 1px #3f58e3;
}
.tariffCards > div.flry {
  background-color: #2c6fd1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #21bbfe, #2c6fd1);
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px rgba(34,50,84,0.5), 1px 1px 0px 1px #2c6fd1;
}
.tariffCards > div.pard {
  background-color: #352f64;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #415197, #352f64);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 60px rgba(34,50,84,0.9), 1px 1px 0px 1px #352f64;
}

.not-selected{
  transition: all .4s ease !important;
  /*z-index: -1 !important;*/
}

.not-selected:hover {
  transform: rotateX(30deg) rotateY(-15deg) rotate(30deg) translate(-25px, 50px) !important;
}

.selected {
  height: 55vh !important;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateX(0px) !important;
  z-index: 3 !important;
}

/*Formulário de inscrição*/
.form-report{
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 2s;
    width: 80%;
}

.form-report form{
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.form-report form input{
    color: black;
    width:100%;
}

.container-btn a{
    background-image: linear-gradient(56deg, #08AEEA 0%, #2AF598 100%);
    border:none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow:0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 4% 0;
    transition: all .2s;
    width: 70%;
}

.container-btn a:hover{
    transform: translateY(3px);
}

body
{
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  -webkit-justify-content: center; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
    </style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tariffCards > div').click(function(){
    var leftPos = $(this).offset().left;
    var topPos = $(this).offset().top;
    var cardWidth = $(this).width();
    var cardHeight = $(this).height();
    var docWidth = $(document).width();  
    var docHeight = $(document).height();  
    var main = $(this);
   
    var moveRight = (docWidth - cardWidth)/2 - leftPos;
    var moveTop = (docHeight - cardHeight)/2 - topPos;
    // console.log(cardWidth)
    // console.log(cardHeight)
    // console.log(leftPos)
    // console.log(moveRight)


    // Cria o Overlay
    $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

    $("#overlay")
      .height(docHeight)
      .css({
         'backdrop-filter': 'blur(3px)',
         'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
         'left': 0,
         'position': 'absolute',
         'top': 0,
         'width': '100%',
         'z-index': 1
      }).fadeIn('3000', function(){
          $('#overlay').show();
      });
    // transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateX(-90%) !important;
    // console.log("")
    // Some com o scroll
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
    // Some com os outros Cards
    $(main).siblings().css("opacity", 0);
    
    // Gira e centraliza o Card @Rever centralização
    setTimeout(function() {
      main.toggleClass('not-selected');
      main.find('h3').css("opacity", 0);
      main.find('span').css("opacity", 0);
      main.toggleClass('selected');
      // Ainda tenho que pensar como centralizar isso de um modo responsivo
      $('.selected').css({"transform": "rotateY(-180deg) translateX(-100%) !important"});
             
      $('.form-report').click(function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
      });
      
      $('#name-input').focus();
    }, 200);  

    setTimeout(function(){
     // Organiza o form dentro do Card
      $('.selected .form-report').css({
          "display":"inherit",
          "opacity": 1,
          "transform":"scaleX(-1)"
      });
    }, 600);
  });
});
 
 // Ao clicar no Overlay
 jQuery('body').on('click', '#overlay', function(){

    var main = $('.selected');

    $('.form-report').fadeOut('300', function(){
      $(this).hide();
    });

    $('#overlay').fadeOut('300',function(){
    $('#overlay').hide();
    });

    main.toggleClass('selected');
    // $('.tariffCards > div')
    // .css({"transform":'rotateX(45deg) rotateY(-15deg) rotate(45deg)', "height":"180px"
    // });

    setTimeout(function() {
      main.toggleClass('not-selected');
      $('.tariffCards > div').siblings().css("opacity", 1);
      $('.tariffCards > div h3').css("opacity", 1);
      $('.tariffCards > div span').css("opacity", 1);
    }, 900);    

    // Reaparece com o scroll
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll')
    
    
 });
</script>

</head>


    <div class="tariffCards">
        <div class="lren not-selected">
            <h3>Lojas Renner<br><br>$LREN3</h3>
            <span>Atualizado em 2T19</span>
            <!--Form aberto ao clicar no relatório-->
            <div class='form-report'>
                <h2>Receba agora.</h2>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id='name-input' placeholder="Nome">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Seu Email">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Celular (SMS de Confirmação)">
                </form>
                
                <br/>

                <div class='container-btn'>
                    <a href="#"><img src='http://edufinance.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/noun_down-arrow.png' width='12%'>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="movi not-selected" id='movi3'>
            <h3>Movida<br><br>$MOVI3</h3>
            <span>Atualizado em 2T19</span>
            <!--Form aberto ao clicar no relatório-->
            <div class='form-report'>
                <h2>Receba agora.</h2>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id='name-input' placeholder="Nome">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Seu Email">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Celular (SMS de Confirmação)">
                </form>
                
                <br/>

                <div class='container-btn'>
                    <a href="#"><img src='http://edufinance.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/noun_down-arrow.png' width='12%'>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flry not-selected" id='flry3'>
            <h3>Fleury S.A.<br><br>$FLRY3</h3>
            <span>Atualizado em 2T19</span>
            <!--Form aberto ao clicar no relatório-->
            <div class='form-report'>
                <h2>Receba agora.</h2>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id='name-input' placeholder="Nome">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Seu Email">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Celular (SMS de Confirmação)">
                </form>
                
                <br/>

                <div class='container-btn'>
                    <a href="#"><img src='http://edufinance.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/noun_down-arrow.png' width='12%'>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pard not-selected" id='pard3'>
            <h3>Hermes Pardini<br><br>$PARD3</h3>
            <span>Atualizado em 2T19</span>
            <!--Form aberto ao clicar no relatório-->
            <div class='form-report'>
                <h2>Receba agora.</h2>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id='name-input' placeholder="Nome">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Seu Email">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Celular (SMS de Confirmação)">
                </form>
                
                <br/>

                <div class='container-btn'>
                    <a href="#"><img src='http://edufinance.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/noun_down-arrow.png' width='12%'>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='home.js'></script>

</html>
```

Comment: BTW your code is so messed up, please try to clean it little bit, Read `HTML` and `CSS`, not try to put anything anywhere  before try in `dev tools` of `browser` read about property is it really helping or just a workaround

Comment: Thanks a lot Dupinder, I'm going to test it. Sorry about the code, I've started learning front-end two weeks ago. I'm still taking my first steps into it.

Comment: it's okay, Use https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp basic knowledge and if you are planning to do more in front-end, please read about `flex` properties its really fun to learn flex-box properties. Use this website this is a fun way to learn flex-box, like a game https://flexboxfroggy.com/ enjoy happy learnings

Comment: Can you explain me why did you take out all the position properties? This is a piece of code that I'm using inside an elementor html widget, thus I can't do a lot of modifications in the body tag. That's the reason why I've setted tariffCards position as absolute.

Comment: you can use them if you need, I just removed for testing purpose, the main reason for the issue was  `transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateX(-128px) !important;` this take the box -128 px from the right position, so you can add them back

Comment: I just checked it and the problem still persists. It's just not apparent because the tariffCard is already centered. Anyway, if you click at the last card, you gonna see that it doesn't allign vertically.

Comment: it's because you are using opacity to hide other cards, use `display:none` to hide other cards. Opacity smudge element in the body, but stay there, Display: none hide the element and free the space so that other element can take place

Comment: try to use display:none to hide elments, this will definalty help